# Why does using the Asynchronous Programming Model in .Net not lead to StackOverflow exceptions?

Tags: .net, asynchronous

For example, we call BeginReceive and have the callback method that BeginReceive executes when it has completed. If that callback method once again calls BeginReceive in my mind it would be very similar to recursion. How is that this does not cause a stackoverflow exception. Example code from MSDN:

```
private static void Receive(Socket client) {
    try {
        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = client;

        // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
        client.BeginReceive( state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}

private static void ReceiveCallback( IAsyncResult ar ) {
    try {
        // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        StateObject state = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;
        Socket client = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the remote device.
        int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0) {
            // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
        state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer,0,bytesRead));

            // Get the rest of the data.
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer,0,StateObject.BufferSize,0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        } else {
            // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
            if (state.sb.Length > 1) {
                response = state.sb.ToString();
            }
            // Signal that all bytes have been received.
            receiveDone.Set();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting question, I wondered about that too - but for some reason I convinced myself that `async` methods are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BeginReceive registers a callback function associated with an overlapped IO operation.  The callback will be called by the operating system when the data is available, but the BeginReceive call returns immediately, and therefore your invocation of ReceiveCallback also finishes.
Think of the actual IO as happening in a thread that doesn't belong to you, but rather to the OS.  Your act of registering the callback just says "keep calling me when something happens", but it doesn't get added to the stack.  That's why it is called asynchronous.

Comment: So if the method call doesn't get pushed on the stack how does it work?

Comment: @uriDium it is pushed on to the stack when next batch of data is available. that is why the stack does not grows on each call and there is no overflow.

Comment: @uriDium which method?  The callback or the BeginReceive?  BeginReceive goes on stack, registers the callback, then returns (and gets removed from stack).  So the OS's thread's stack is like this: 1) __receive_some_io 2) ReceiveCallback 3) BeginReceive.  That's it, never gets deeper than that. Are you familiar with setTimeout() function in JavaScript by any chance?

Answer (score 3):

An interesting question, but after you call `BeginReceive`, your function continues to execute and then eventually returns, so there is no real recursion there.

Comment: recursion isn't dictated by the structure of the method.  There are recursive samples in Axum that use this style.

Answer (score 2):

Because the `BeginReceive` calls onto another arbitrary thread - each thread contains their own stack.  Even though the same code is running, the stack never gets deep enough on a given thread to cause an exception.  The stack unwinds if the call across to the other thread is non-blocking - it makes the call then continues as normal.  You would get issues if they each waited, but never returned.

In your sample, depending on the code path - it could arguably run forever.  The idea is similar to co-routines, where methods constantly call each other in a crude ping-pong fashion, but again no stack issues.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
client.BeginReceive(state.buffer,0,StateObject.BufferSize,0, 
    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
```

does **not** automatically call the ReceiveCallback method, that method is called when the operation is finished.

In the meantime, the method that called the `BeginReceive` continues executing, doing whatever it does, and returning happily, thus removing itself from the stack.

When you use recursion, every call adds a stack frame *(see comment)*, that is not popped until the called method returns, so the stack grows until the recursion is done.

Comment: [Pedantically] When you use recursion, *and the compiler doesn't (or cannot) apply tail optimisation*, every call adds a stack frame. The difference allows idiomatic functional code to avoid stack overflows (.NET includes support in some cases).

Comment: So how does asyncronous methods work in terms of the stack? Also how expensive is the callback and how does that work? Does it need to copy all of the class variables as well?

Comment: As someone mentioned, the async callbacks are not guaranteed to execute on the same thread, so you might have another stack altogether. Other that that, they are like any other method... And I really haven't tested if there is a performance impact from using async calls, but my opinion is that async methods will make the app more responsive, even if the overhead is increased.